# Python web spider and issue with finding the right link

Tags: python, web-crawler

So I have made a web spider which scans all links on given site and I've configured two conditions for him to check out.

code:

```
import urllib
import re
import mechanize
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urlparse
import cookielib
from urlparse import urlsplit
from publicsuffix import PublicSuffixList

url = "http://www.physiotherme.com"

br = mechanize.Browser()
cj = cookielib.LWPCookieJar()
br.set_cookiejar(cj)
br.set_handle_robots(False)
br.set_handle_equiv(False)
br.set_handle_redirect(True)
br.set_handle_refresh(mechanize._http.HTTPRefreshProcessor(), max_time=1)
br.addheaders = [('User-agent', 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US; rv:1.9.0.1) Gecko/2008071615 Fedora/3.0.1-1.fc9 Firefox/3.0.1')]
page = br.open(url, timeout=10)

htmlcontent = page.read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(htmlcontent)

urls = set()
contact_keys = ["impressum", "kontakt"]
found_contact_urls = {}

for link in br.links(text_regex=re.compile('^((?!IMG).)*$')):
    new_url = urlparse.urljoin(link.base_url, link.url)
    urls.add(new_url)
    for key in contact_keys:
        if key in new_url:
            found_contact_urls[key] = new_url
            break
for key in contact_keys:
    if key in found_contact_urls:
        print found_contact_urls[key]
        break
    else:
        print url
        break
```

The idea is that spider checks out links in set and if he finds that one with `'impressum'` in it it prints it out, if not, he prints out that one with `'kontakt'` in it.

If neither of those two links are not found then he prints out the address of main site.

The following site (http://www.physiotherme.com) that I'm checking out does not have link with `'impressum'` but does have link with `'kontakt'` word.

But my spider does not prints out that link `http://www.physiotherme.com/kontakt.html` , he prints out that one from main site `http://www.physiotherme.com`, even that one with `'kontakt'` is in my url set. If I put `print urls` on end, I'm seeing wanted link in set:

```
set(['http://www.physiotherme.com/sauna.html', 'http://www.physiotherme.com/kontakt.html', 'http://www.physiotherme.com/offen.html'])
```

So I don't know what is problem with my code. Why he does not prints out `http://www.physiotherme.com/kontakt.html`?

Edit:

just noticed, if I remove

```
else:
    print url
    break
```

the link with `kontakt` gets printed out. But that is not my solution because, on some other case with different website, I want to print main url if neither of those two in `contact_keys` is not found..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The logic of your code is not consistent with your description. The last part of your code should be:

```
for link in br.links(text_regex=re.compile('^((?!IMG).)*$')):
    new_url = urlparse.urljoin(link.base_url, link.url)
    ......

key_found_flag = False
for key in contact_keys:
    if key in found_contact_urls.keys():   
        print found_contact_urls[key]
        key_found_flag = True
        break
if not key_found_flag:
    print url
```